# Jira: Cannot update profile when logging in via OpenID

Tags: jira, openid, atlassian-crowd, jira-agile

I am trying to update my profile on the following page:

> https://jira.company-name.io/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?selectedTab=jira.user.profile.panels:user-profile-summary-panel

However, I get "wrong password" error when using personal access token created in Jira account. On the other hand, I think the error is caused by using OpenID for logging to Jira account. So, in this case, actually there is no password for the account but when updating profile, password is also required (I use personal access token for this field).

So, how can I update profile on my Jira account? What should I use as password when I login via OpenID connect?

[image]

Comment: That API token isn't for web interactions, it's for API interactions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. Then, how can I update profile when I login using OpenId Connect?

Comment: @DanielAgans Chico? Are you there?